# Size of image in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am wondering about an image in a view. Let's assume i have a view of 300x300 and inside i place an image of arbitrary size. I use resizeMode='contain' to fit the whole image into the view. If the image exceeds 300x300 it's fine, but if it's smaller then it stretches to the borders. Is there any way of keeping original image size if it's smaller than it's view?

Cheers!

Comment: Does `resizeMode=center` not do what you want?

Comment: @AaronGolden it would work for me but it cuts off part of image if it's too big